# linux create directories and move corresponding files to the directories

Tags: linux, for-loop, text, mv

I have a text file listed the directory names and what files should included inside.

```
my text file:
SRS000111    ERR1045156     
SRS000112    ERR1045188     
SRS000123    ERR1045204     
SRS000134    ERR1045237  ERR1045238  ERR1045239
SRS000154    ERR1045255  ERR1045256 
SRS000168    ERR1045260  ERR1045261  ERR1045262
...          ...         ...
SRS001567    ERR1547451  ERR1547676
```

now I want to create all the directories using the first column of the text file but I don't know how to do the for loop.

```
for filename in cat file.txt | awk -F, '{print $1}'; do mkdir ${filename}; done
```

but it goes to error.

second I have all the ERR files and I want to move them to the corresponding directories according to the text file. I have not any idea how to do this part.

Comment: What is the delimiter between the column in every line ?

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S tab

Answer (score 1):

You have to make `system` calls from awk for `mkdir` and `mv` files

This **awk** would do

```
awk 'FNR>1{system("mkdir \"" $1 "\""); for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) system("mv \"" $i "\" " "\"" $1 "\"")}' file
```

`FNR>1` because we don't want to create directory for first line i.e header names in your CSV file

Note : Run this command from the directory where all the filenames as mentioned in your source/input file are present. This will create directories there itself and will move all the files in those newly created directories.

Comment: mv: rename ERR1045156 to SRS000111/ERR1045156: No such file or directory

Comment: @PeterChung: You are not running the command from where the file `ERR1045156` is placed. `cd` to the `directory` where all your files are placed and then run this command as I mentioned in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read the file, split the folder name columns and file name columns and makes de directories and the movements.

This script makes it:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  dir=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
  files=$(echo "$line" | awk '{$1=""; print $0}')

  mkdir $dir
  mv $files $dir/
done < myfile.txt
```

Is not to complicated but if you have questions about it you can make me any question